# Cannot use ALL ROWS in a SOQL subquery?

Tags: soql, tasks, allrows, subquery

I need to query all Tasks from a Case, and some of the Tasks are over a year old, which makes them invisible to SOQL unless you use the [ALL ROWS keyword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm).

I tried to use ALL ROWS in the subquery, but got a compiler error.   Did not see it documented anywhere.

```
List<Case> cases = [select id, (select id from Tasks ALL ROWS) from Case];
```

I have to resort to using two queries.  Where is this documented?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want all `Task` records related to a `Case`, you can filter on `What.Type`:

```
List<Task> records = [SELECT WhatId FROM Task WHERE What.Type = 'Case' ALL ROWS];
```

You can still group them by parent quite easily:

```
Map<Id, List<Task>> caseIdToTasks = new Map<Id, List<Task>>();
for (Task record : [/*query*/])
{
    if (!caseIdToTasks.containsKey(record.WhatId))
        caseIdToTasks.put(record.WhatId, new List<Task>());
    caseItToTasks.get(record.WhatId).add(record);
}
```